# Find a Value in Table Using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle

I inherited a large database and nobody seems to know which table/column a particular data set is coming from. I've spent a lot of time going through table by table in Oracle's SQL Developer, but I can't find it. Is there a way in SQLDeveloper to search the entire table for a single value. Something like:

```
select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_value='desired value';
```

The db has around 1K+ tables each with lots of columns so manually combing through this isn't working.

Comment: It is impossible for you to be simultaneously using MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle at the same time. Please do **NOT** just randomly add tags that sound familiar to your question. Add **only the tags that are actually relevant**. If you're not sure, read the tag description. If you're not sure after that, don't add the tag; if it's needed, someone here will add it. Tags have specific meaning.

Comment: Those were the SO suggested tags. Now removed.

Comment: People keep suggesting edits to my tags. I am just approving them as they come in. I'm using the desktop software SQLDeveloper by Oracle. Tag the post however, you see fit.

Comment: `sql-server` tag is for Microsoft SQL Server, your `oracle` tag is appropriate..

Comment: Well, you can monitor what queries have been executed from the v$sqlarea view, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to search for a value in all columns of your schema. The execution time for the script will depend on the number of tables in your schema and the number of rows in each of your table.

Replace 'abc' with the value which you intend to search. Also, right now the script will search all VARCHAR2 columns. You can also insert the table names and counts into a table instead of doing a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.

```
DECLARE 

    CURSOR cur_tables 
    IS 
    SELECT table_name, 
           column_name 
    FROM   user_tab_columns
    WHERE  data_type = 'VARCHAR2';

    v_sql         VARCHAR2(4000);

    v_value       VARCHAR2(50);
    v_count       NUMBER;

BEGIN

    v_value := 'abc';

    FOR c_tables IN cur_tables LOOP
        v_sql := 'SELECT count(1) FROM ' ||  c_tables.table_name || ' WHERE ' || c_tables.column_name || ' = :val' ;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_count USING v_value;
        IF v_count > 0 THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table Name ' ||  c_tables.table_name || ' Column Name ' || c_tables.column_name || ' Row Count ' || v_count);
        END IF; 
    END LOOP;
END;
```